# Python Multiprocessing a For Loop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

My script doesn't work. All 10 Processes take the first list item, then stop. output 10x 1 list entry
How to fix this? Error must be in the loop or do I need a queue for this?

```
import finanzen_fundamentals.stocks as ff
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import time

results = []

def get_list():
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect( host="localhost", user="changed", password="changed", database="stockdata")
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("select * from url_name")
        record = mycursor.fetchall()
        return record
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

def create_json(record):
    for row in record:
        try:
            df = ff.get_current_value_lxml(str(row[2])[:-1], exchange = "FSE")
            print('Name:' + row[0] + ' WKN:' + df['wkn'].values[0] + ' Preis:' + str(df['price'].values[0]) + ' Currency:' + df['currency'].values[0] + ' Zeit:' + df['time'].values[0])
            result = [[row[0], df['wkn'].values[0], df['price'].values[0], df['currency'].values[0], df['time'].values[0]]]
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

def collect_results(result):
     results.extend(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    record = get_list()
    start_time = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(create_json, args=(record, ), callback=collect_results)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    df_out = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Name', 'WKN', 'Preis', 'Currency', 'Zeit'])
    print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                      Name     WKN  Preis Currency        Zeit
0  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
1  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
2  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
3  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
4  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
5  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
6  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
7  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
8  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
9  21VIANET GRP ADR A/6 O.  A1H9DT   20.0      EUR  23.10.2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the loops structure wrong. Inside `create_json` you are looping the `row`s of `record` but you always call it with the same original `record` list and **`return` on the first iteration**. So all workers will always just work on the first line. You need to change the worker function to operate on a `row`:

```py
def create_json(row):
    try:
        df = ff.get_current_value_lxml(str(row[2])[:-1], exchange = "FSE")
        print('Name:' + row[0] + ' WKN:' + df['wkn'].values[0] + ' Preis:' + str(df['price'].values[0]) + ' Currency:' + df['currency'].values[0] + ' Zeit:' + df['time'].values[0])
        result = [[row[0], df['wkn'].values[0], df['price'].values[0], df['currency'].values[0], df['time'].values[0]]]
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

And then call it with each row, in the main code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    for row in record:
        pool.apply_async(create_json, args=(row, ), callback=collect_results)
    ...
```

---

Note that in this case, instead of looping and calling [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async), you can just use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map). It even already returns a list of the results so **you don't even need the `callback` anymore**, something like:

```py
def create_json(row):
    try:
        df = ff.get_current_value_lxml(str(row[2])[:-1], exchange = "FSE")
        print('Name:' + row[0] + ' WKN:' + df['wkn'].values[0] + ' Preis:' + str(df['price'].values[0]) + ' Currency:' + df['currency'].values[0] + ' Zeit:' + df['time'].values[0])
        result = [row[0], df['wkn'].values[0], df['price'].values[0], df['currency'].values[0], df['time'].values[0]]
        # NOTE THAT NOW IT'S A 1-D LIST!
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    record = get_list()
    start_time = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        results = pool.map(create_json, record)

    df_out = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Name', 'WKN', 'Preis', 'Currency', 'Zeit'])
    print(df_out)
```

Comment: Your answer works pretty well, but it isn't as fast as excepted. Do you have any recommendations to improve the speed? (Of course better Hardware but at first Softwareside?). Here my updatet Method:   
def on_call():
    record = get_list()
    start_time = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    for row in record:
        pool.apply_async(create_json, args=(row, ), callback=collect_results)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

Comment: Did you try the `map` version I provided? It might be faster because the loop is internal and not an explicit `for`. You might also try with a thread pool by changing the `import` to [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) but not sure if that will make it better because of [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)